# How to emulate Android Multiple Screen?

Tags: android, screen, emulation

How to handle Android multiple screen? Confusing...

I read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) and [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) Now I'm confused about this range small, normal, large and xlarge. I tried my app on Galaxy Note it works well on real device. But strangely it is not on the emulator. I even tried to use custom AVD that really specific define Galaxy note e.g. 800 x 1280 with 285 density. But result looks ugly on emulator.

I have problems with other devices too. SGS 2, HD Devices and other devices...All the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) seems invalid and inaccurate.

How to emulate perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Galaxy Note AVD skin from [this](https://github.com/downloads/rayesh/android-emulator-skins/Galaxy%20Note.zip) link, also
see [this](http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/) article for help and reference.

Comment: Thanks for the links. However I want to be able to emulate all possibilities.

Comment: To emulate all screen sizes and resolution, you can create different emulators. But you can not expect that an emulator can be 100% accurate. After all its a simulation of the real device and have some [limitations](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html).